# How to do a conditional aggregation after a groupby in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to group by an ID column in a `pyspark` dataframe and sum a column depending on the value of another column.

To illustrate, consider the following dummy dataframe:

```py
+-----+-------+---------+
|   ID|   type|   amount|
+-----+-------+---------+
|    1|      a|       55|
|    2|      b|     1455|
|    2|      a|       20|
|    2|      b|      100|
|    3|   null|      230|
+-----+-------+---------+
```

My desired output is:

```py
+-----+--------+----------+----------+
|   ID|   sales|   sales_a|   sales_b|
+-----+--------+----------+----------+
|    1|      55|        55|         0| 
|    2|    1575|        20|      1555|        
|    3|     230|         0|         0|
+-----+--------+----------+----------+
```

So basically, `sales` will be the sum of `amount`, while `sales_a` and `sales_b` are the sum of `amount` when `type` is `a` or `b` respectively.

For `sales`, I know this could be done like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.groupBy("ID").agg(F.sum("amount").alias("sales"))
```

For the others, I'm guessing `F.when` would be useful but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create two columns before the aggregation based off of the value of type.

```
df.withColumn("sales_a", F.when(col("type") == "a", col("amount"))) \
  .withColumn("sales_b", F.when(col("type") == "b", col("amount"))) \
  .groupBy("ID") \
  .agg(F.sum("amount").alias("sales"),
       F.sum("sales_a").alias("sales_a"),
       F.sum("sales_b").alias("sales_b"))
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do it without the extra columns? something like:
`df.groupBy("ID").agg(F.when(F.col("type") == a, F.sum("amount")).alias("sales_a"))`

Comment: yep that should work as well. check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53458150/conditional-aggregation-using-pyspark

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.groupBy("ID").agg(F.sum("amount").alias("sales"))
dfPivot = df.filter("type is not null").groupBy("ID").pivot("type").agg(F.sum("amount").alias("sales"))

res = df.join(dfPivot, df.id== dfPivot.id,how='left')
```

Then replace `null` with `0`.
This is generic solution will work irrespective of values in `type` column.. so if `type` c is added in dataframe then it will create column `_c`