# Quarter to date growth

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some *daily* data in a `df`, which goes back as far as 1st January 2020. It looks similar to the below but with many `id1`s on each day.

```
| yyyy_mm_dd | id1 | id2  | cost  |
|------------|-----|------|-------|
| 2020-01-01 | 23  | 7253 | 5003  |
| 2020-01-01 | 23  | 7743 | 30340 |
| 2020-01-02 | 23  | 7253 | 450   |
| 2020-01-02 | 23  | 7743 | 4500  |
| ...        | ... | ...  | ...   |
| 2021-01-01 | 23  | 7253 | 5675  |
| 2021-01-01 | 23  | 134  | 1030  |
| 2021-01-01 | 23  | 3445 | 564   |
| 2021-01-01 | 23  | 4534 | 345   |
| ...        | ... | ...  | ...   |
```

I have grouped and calculated the summed cost like so:

```
grouped_quarterly = (
    df
    .withColumn('year_quarter', (F.year(F.col('yyyy_mm_dd')) * 100 + F.quarter(F.col('yyyy_mm_dd'))
    .groupby('id1', 'year_quarter')
    .agg(
        F.sum('cost').alias('cost')
    )
)
```

I am able to then successfully make a quarter over quarter comparison like so:

```
w = Window.partitionBy(F.col('id1'), F.expr('substring(string(year_quarter), -2)')).orderBy('year_quarter')
growth = (
    grouped_quarterly
    .withColumn('prev_value', F.lag(F.col('cost')).over(w))
    .withColumn('diff', F.when(F.isnull(F.col('cost') - F.col('prev_value')), 0).otherwise(F.col('cost') - F.col('prev_value')))
).where(F.col('year_quarter') >= 202101)
```

I would like to modify this to be quarter to date instead of quarter over quarter. For example, the above would compare April 1st 2020 - June 30th 2020 with April 1st 2020 - April 15th 2021 (or whatever maximum date in df is).

Instead, I would prefer to compare April 1st 2020 - April 15th 2020 with April 1st 2021 - April 15th 2021.

Is it possible to ensure only the same periods are compared within year_quarter?

**Edit:** Adding sample output:

---

```
grouped_quarterly.where(F.col('id1') == 222).sort('year_quarter').show(10,False)

| id1 | year_quarter | cost  |
|-----|--------------|-------|
| 222 | 202001       | 49428 |
| 222 | 202002       | 43292 |
| 222 | 202003       | 73928 |
| 222 | 202004       | 12028 |
| 222 | 202101       | 19382 |
| 222 | 202102       | 4282  |

growth.where(F.col('id1') == 222).sort('year_quarter').show(10,False)

| id1 | year_quarter | cost  | prev_value | diff   | growth |
|-----|--------------|-------|------------|--------|--------|
| 222 | 202101       | 52494 | 49428      | 3066   | 6.20   |
| 222 | 202102       | 4282  | 43292      | -39010 | -90.10 |
```

The growth calculation from the window is being done correctly. However, since 202102 is in progress, it gets compared to the full 202002. The comparison for 202101 works perfectly as both year_quarters are complete.

Is there anyway to ensure the window function only compares the same period within the year_quarter with the previous year, for incomplete quarters? I hope the sample data makes my question a bit more clear

Comment: when compating quarter 2/2021 with quarter 2/2020, only the data from April 1st - April 15th should be taken into account in both years. But what about 2/2020 vs. 2/2019? Should we compare April 1st - June 30th 2020 with April 1st - June 30th 2019 or rather April 1st - April 15th 2020 with April 1st - April 15th 2019?

Comment: The full quarter should be compared unless it's currently in progress. As both 2019Q2 and 2020Q2 are complete, it should be be April 1st - June 30th comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to split the task into two parts:

1. Calculate the growth for the complete quarters. This logic is completely taken over from the question and then
2. calculate the growth for the currently running quarter.

First generate some additional test data for 2019Q2, 2020Q2 and 2021Q2:

```python
data = [('2019-04-01', 23, 1), ('2019-04-01', 23, 2), ('2019-04-02', 23, 3), ('2019-04-15', 23, 4),
        ('2019-04-16', 23, 5), ('2019-04-17', 23, 6), ('2019-05-01', 23, 7), ('2019-06-30', 23, 8),
        ('2019-07-01', 23, 9), ('2020-01-01',23,5003),('2020-01-01',23,30340), ('2020-01-02',23,450),
        ('2020-01-02',23,4500), ('2020-04-01', 23, 10), ('2020-04-01', 23, 20), ('2020-04-02', 23, 30),
        ('2020-04-15', 23, 40), ('2020-04-16', 23, 50), ('2020-04-17', 23, 60), ('2020-05-01', 23, 70),
        ('2020-06-30', 23, 80), ('2020-07-01', 23, 90), ('2021-01-01',23,5675), ('2021-01-01',23,1030),
        ('2021-01-01',23,564), ('2021-01-01',23,345), ('2021-04-01', 23, -10), ('2021-04-01', 23, -20),
        ('2021-04-02', 23, -30), ('2021-04-15', 23, -40)]
```

Calcuate the `year_quarter` column and cache the result:

```python
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = ["yyyy_mm_dd", "id1", "cost"]) \
    .withColumn("yyyy_mm_dd", F.to_date("yyyy_mm_dd", "yyyy-MM-dd")) \
    .withColumn('year_quarter', (F.year(F.col('yyyy_mm_dd')) * 100 + F.quarter(F.col('yyyy_mm_dd')))) \
    .cache()
```

Get the maximum date and its corresponding quarter:

```python
max_row = df.selectExpr("max(yyyy_mm_dd)", "max_by(year_quarter, yyyy_mm_dd)").head()
cur_date, cur_quarter = max_row[0], max_row[1]
```

It is not strictly necessary to set `cur_date` to the maximum date of the data. Instead `cur_date` and `cur_quarter` could also be set manually.

For all quarters but the current one apply the logic given in the question:

```python
w = Window.partitionBy(F.col('id1'), F.expr('substring(string(year_quarter), -2)')).orderBy('year_quarter')
df_full_quarters = df.filter(f"year_quarter <> {cur_quarter}") \
    .groupby('id1', 'year_quarter') \
    .agg(F.sum('cost').alias('cost')) \
    .withColumn('prev_value', F.lag(F.col('cost')).over(w))
```

For the current quarter filter out all dates in the previous year that should be ignored:

```python
df_cur_quarter = df.filter(f"year_quarter = {cur_quarter} or (year_quarter = {cur_quarter - 100} and add_months(yyyy_mm_dd, 12) <= '{cur_date}')") \
    .groupby('id1', 'year_quarter') \
    .agg(F.sum('cost').alias('cost')) \
    .withColumn('prev_value', F.lag(F.col('cost')).over(w)) \
    .filter(f"year_quarter = {cur_quarter}")
```

Finally union the two parts and calculate the `diff` column:

```python
growth = df_full_quarters.union(df_cur_quarter) \
    .withColumn('diff', F.when(F.isnull(F.col('cost') - F.col('prev_value')), 0).otherwise(F.col('cost') - F.col('prev_value'))) \
    .orderBy("id1", "year_quarter")
```

The result will be:

```
+---+------------+-----+----------+------+                                      
|id1|year_quarter| cost|prev_value|  diff|
+---+------------+-----+----------+------+
| 23|      201902|   36|      null|     0|
| 23|      201903|    9|      null|     0|
| 23|      202001|40293|      null|     0|
| 23|      202002|  360|        36|   324|
| 23|      202003|   90|         9|    81|
| 23|      202101| 7614|     40293|-32679|
| 23|      202102| -100|       100|  -200|
+---+------------+-----+----------+------+
```

In this example, for the comparison of 2021Q2 with the previous year the sum for 2020Q2 is given as 100, but the actual value for the full 2020Q2 is 360.

Comment: Hey.. I am testing this now but unfortunately `max_by` is not available since I am using PySpark 2.2.0. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @stackq yes, you can simply take the value of `cur_date` and then re-calculate the value of `cur_quarter` with the logic you already used in your question

Answer (score 1):

If you want quarter to date comparison YoY but quarter is incomplete, then do agg by

`dayofmonth(col("input")).alias("dayofmonth")`

if current quarter being compared to is equal to current month of current year maybe with `.agg(when(col("date_column") condition exp))`

Some more insights [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53458150/conditional-aggregation-using-pyspark)

Comment: I'm unsure how to tie it together. Do you think you can modify your answer to show a more complete solution?